# Assertion error expectation failure EasyMock

Tags: junit, mocking, easymock

I have the next JUnit test, and it works fine, but finally in the verify it throws expectation failure. I think it is because the mocked `PsPort` is different of the `PsPort` that I send to the `DataReader`.
Is there any other way to test it?

```java
    @Test
    public void testguardarMensaje() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException{

        String datoTest = "1=123456";   

        Constructor<PsPort> constructor = PsPort.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] {String.class});
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        PsPort port = constructor.newInstance("middleware.conf");

        PsPort drMock;

        int hash1 = datoTest.hashCode();
        String hashString1 = String.valueOf(hash1);
        String combinedIdDataHashString1 = datoTest +"="+ hashString1;

        drMock = strictMock(PsPort.class);
        byte[] datoByte = port.encriptarDesencriptarMensaje(combinedIdDataHashString1.getBytes(), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        drMock.guardarDato(datoByte);
        replayAll();

        int hash = datoTest.hashCode();
        String hashString = String.valueOf(hash);
        String combinedIdDataHashString = datoTest +"="+ hashString;

        byte[] datoByte2 = port.encriptarDesencriptarMensaje(combinedIdDataHashString.getBytes(), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);

        DatagramPacket paquete = new DatagramPacket(datoByte2,datoByte2.length);
        paquete.getData();

        DataReader dr = new DataReader(port, null, 100, "=", "C:/Users/Asier/Desktop/logs/");

        dr.guardarMensaje(paquete, port);
        verifyAll();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really confusing that you have two port objects. What is the sense of creating a mocked drPort; when you are then giving a "real" port object to your class under test?

You see: you either create a mock and pass that down to your code under test (and then you have to setup the mock for the expected behavior; which you can afterwards verify); or you only provide "real" objects to your code under test, but then you would normally do some kind of asserts on the results of calls to "code under test".

So, in that sense, it doesn't really matter that there is at least one problem in your code:

```
drMock.guardarDato(datoByte);
replayAll();
```

There should be a call to `EasyMock.expectLastCall()` after the method invocation on drMock; but as said: as the mocked object isn't really used, that doesn't matter, on the one hand. Because, if you added that statement, your test would always fail; since your un-used mock would never see the calls that you specified it to see.

In order to give you some guidance; this is how you do such kind of testing in general:

```
SomeClassYouNeed mockedThingy = createStrict/Nice(SomeClassYouNeed.class);
expect(mockedThingy.foo()).andReturn("whatever");
mockedThingy.bar();
expectLastCall();
replay (mockedThingy);

ClassUnderTest underTest = new ClassUnderTest(mockedThingy);
underTest.doSomething();

verify(mockedThingy)
```

Meaning: any "object" that

a) your "class under test" needs to do its work 
b) you want/have to "control" in a certain way

needs to be mocked; including a "specification" of all expected method calls.

Then you provide the mocked things to your code under test; execute the method you want to test ... to finally verify that the mock saw the behavior that you specified for it.